# Are QStrings mutable?

Tags: programming, qt, ubuntu-sdk

In python; strings are not mutable as far as I know. To change a string in python, you would have to create a new object.

Is this the same for QString?

Comment: Shouldn't this better be placed at www.stackoverflow.com?

Comment: ubuntu sdk - based on qtcreator. qt is the central language for gui development on ubuntu.

Comment: All right, I added the ubuntu-sdk tag to make it more clear.

Comment: Still think this is better suited to SO, since QStrings being immutable or not has nothing to do with Ubuntu, no more than Java (or Python) Strings being immutable or not.

Comment: I agree that this has nothing to do with Ubuntu. Reasoning that this question is related to Ubuntu because of Qt being used in Ubuntu development is the same as justifying to ask anything about any programming language that has a part in Ubuntu development - which is not the purpose of this site. Nevertheless: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstring.html#details -> QString is mutable.

Comment: This was a comment on another question asked about qml -- http://askubuntu.com/questions/446755/what-does-gu-stand-for -- `Note to closers: QML is a core progamming language for ubuntu & ubuntu-touch and hence is on-topic here - remember we like ubuntu related programming questions. –  fossfreedom♦ Apr 12 at 7:42`

Comment: Akiva key phrase being "ubuntu related". And QML is not the same as Qt. One can make a case for a question about a function used for UI being on-topic, but how can you use that to justify this? @AhtiKomu at any rate, can you post that as an answer, so we can be done with this question?

Comment: QML is Qt. Just about every Core App uses explicit Qt Code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As can be seen in the [QString documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstring.html#details), QString is a mutable object.